Mongo how to convert id to string without losing all fields
I am trying to convert id to string in aggregate function with
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }

But for some reason i am losing all other fields after aggregation and get only "_id" field. What should i change?
Mongo Playground

When you use $project on _id explicitly and with an expression or 1 then it's like selecting only the _id field.
Usually, _id is included by default so the usage is like { $project: { _id: 0 } } - the 0 means "don't include _id in the result" but include all other fields.
Read more about the behaviour of $project here.
Instead, just use $set:
  {
    "$set": {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }

Your Mongo Playground example, with the fix.
